# Water flow sensor still active after water stops

Tags: water, flow-sensor

I have a water flow sensor that uses a rotor with a Hall sensor (ATS177 SIP-3 Hall effect sensor latch). The problem is that the rotor keeps spinning for some time after the water flow stops.

**Video on the problem:**
https://youtu.be/33CNrsudbgc
At 1 sec in the syringe stop but the rotor is still spinning.

I think this is a problem for all flowmeter sensor. Is this why they write that its a 10% error reading? If no how do they fix this with some algorithms? If this is the case. Can anyone help me how an algorithm will look like.

**My question**
How do I solve this wrong measurements? Do I need to make a design change of the rotor case? If I need to make it work with some script, it’s more the general idea how the script will work. Not specific script language.

Comment: Erik Andershed - Hi, Please can you [edit] your question to add more details of the sensor, a schematic for your design, details of how you are reading the sensor, and exactly where you are stuck. You ask how to write "a script" but you don't specify a language (Python? Bash shell script? Something else?). Depending on your overall design, the solution might be code in another language or even some hardware changes, rather than a script. So although an algorithm similar to debouncing a push-switch is probably applicable, it would help readers if you can add more details & context. Thanks.

Comment: The only thing that would allow the rotor to keep spinning is if it were in air or a vacuum but then only for a short time. How do you know if the rotor is still spinning. Post a schematic of your test circuit, not a frizzy picture.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a software question - "How do I write a script", not an electronics question.

Comment: It could be a "what is the transfer function of my system" question, which is arguably within EE. If you have another sensor with better response, get some steps response data, and calibrate from that.

Comment: I will update this question with more data to show the problem tomorrow. Please wait

Comment: It is ok if it spins for two more seconds.

Comment: No, sorry in this device I need a way to stop right after the flow is stopped.

Comment: After the syringe stops applying force, how long until the water stops coming out the far end of the tube?

Comment: I think right a way. Let me dubble check this tomorrow

Comment: The water is stop the same time as the syringe stops.

Comment: @ErikAndershed - Hi, I watched the video, but at only 2 s long, it's too short & too "zoomed in" for me to properly see the flow of liquid around the various parts, to understand the system. Also clear liquid is hard to see. It's unclear which parts of the design are *yours* e.g. the rotating part? This seems to be more of a mechanical issue than an electronics one, if (as you seem to be saying) with *stationary* liquid the rotor is still moving - clearances too big? You *seem* unsure too, as you ask about whether to change the rotor case, but that's not an electronics problem, is it? Sorry.

Comment: Yes I know I am asking if there is a design error or if this is common function of an water flow sensor and that is an electronics question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will find an off-the-shelf algorithm for this.

You will need to conduct an experiment with various flow rates, durations, ramp rates, etc, and measure the error in these cases. If you can quantify it, you can cancel it out.

Unfortunately the properties of the rotor may also change over time as the bushing wears, but if you want the best possible accuracy it's not uncommon to test and re-calibrate any sensor periodically.